# Continuous connection via HttpGet?

Tags: java, android, json, get, httprequest

Hey all I am writing an android aplication which gets a JSON object from a node.js server. My code is below (I do not have access to the server code). Is there any way to consistently check the server for a change in the JSON object (if they update it)? Right now it only does one GET and stops. I want to be able to query for a change and continue working with the new updates. Thoughts? Thanks.

Called from OnCreate():

```
new Read().execute("JSONkey");
```

Here is my Read ASyncTask:

```
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...param) {
        try {
            read_json = getCoords();
            httpText.append(read_json.toString() + "\n");
            try{
            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            JSONArray data = read_json.getJSONArray(param[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i){
                JSONObject info = data.getJSONObject(i);
                Coordinate pt = new Coordinate(info.getInt("point"), info.getString("name"), info.getDouble("lat"), info.getDouble("long"));
                coords.put(pt.getPoint(), pt);
                coordList.add(new GeoPoint(pt.getLat(),pt.getLong()));
            }
            return "Success"; //get "text"

        } catch (Exception e){
            return "Fail";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        //Doing something with JSON

        //new Read().execute("coords"); tried doing this, but I feel it is not right.


    }
}
```

and the GetCoords():

```
 public JSONObject getCoords() 
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONObject last = new JSONObject(data);
        return last;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend using sockets or even better gcm. Continiously polling server will dramatically affect the server and the battery of your mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with a WebSocket but given the constrain of not being able to control the server side, your best bet is to

Put your code inside a service:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Then use the Alarm Manager to schedule periodic updates.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html